# CameraX unit testing Android

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, camera, android-camerax

I`m begginer in unit testing. The more I read, the less I understand what to do.
I'm trying to write unit tests for the cameraX, but I'm having trouble figuring it out. Here is my code now

My method:

```
  fun startCamera() {
    val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(requireContext())
    cameraProviderFuture.addListener(
        {
            cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()

            val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.Builder()
                .requireLensFacing(cameraSelectorOption)
                .build()

            setCameraConfig(cameraProvider, cameraSelector)

        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(requireContext())
    )
}
```

My unit test:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
```

class CameraFragmentTest {

```
@get:Rule
val permissionRule = GrantPermissionRule.grant(
    Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
)

@get:Rule
val activityRule: ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> = ActivityTestRule(MainActivity::class.java)

@Mock
lateinit var cameraProviderFuture: ProcessCameraProvider
lateinit var processCameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider
private lateinit var mockContext: Context

@Test
fun useAppContext() {
    val context = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext() as Context
    assertEquals("com.android.example.studyprojectrnc", context.packageName)
}

@Test
fun testStartCamera() {

    //init
    val cameraFragment : CameraFragment = mock()

    //work
    val result = cameraFragment.startCamera()

    //assert
    Assert.assertEquals(result)
}
```

}

I would be very grateful for an example of test writing

Also maybe you can recommend what else I can read or any courses on testing (although a lot of information in my head is already making me crazy)

So... Please help me understand this т_т

Answer (score 2):

I believe this would help, official Sample app for cameraX
https://github.com/android/camera-samples/blob/main/CameraXBasic/app/src/androidTest/java/com/android/example/cameraxbasic/CameraPreviewTest.kt